# iOS unable to set element position programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am unable to set label and image position programmatically. I am trying to set is as,

```
navBarSocial.frame = CGRectMake(navBarSocial.frame.origin.x, navBarSocial.frame.origin.y, webView1.frame.size.width, navBarSocial.frame.size.height);

 status.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, status.frame.size.width, status.frame.size.height);
 loadingImage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, loadingImage.frame.size.width, loadingImage.frame.size.height);
```

navBarSocial increase its witdth properly but label (status) and loadingImage remains at same position. I also set autosizing properties deactivated on xib but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of your question.  You speak of position, which makes sense they are staying in the same position as you have statically set them to x = 100 and y = 50.  In terms of size, it seems you are setting the size to the current size of the item.  In other words you are passing the current size in as the size you want to set the element you are trying to resize to.

Comment: Elements are not at desired pos 100, 50 but must be after execution. Not trying to resize! only pos set. I could use also CGPointMake but same result

Comment: I have seen this before, and it has indeed happened in programs I have written for MacOS X and iOS.  Just out of curiosity, what happens if you put a:    [status setNeedsLayout] and [loadingImage setNeedsLayout] after you have set the frames, or a [superview setNeedsLayout]???

Answer (score 1):

```
 loadingImage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, loadingImage.frame.size.width, loadingImage.frame.size.height);
```

`loadingImage` sets it's width to its width and its height to its height. What do you expect to change? You probably need to change the width and the height to something different that it already has..
Setting geometry should be done in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear` methods. Also check your outlet connections.
Btw use only properties, not ivars.

Comment: No, I would like only to set a new position, not its width and height! like CGPointMake. Outlets are correct because I set other properties properly and position needs to be set while execution and not on suggested events :(

Comment: So when you change the origin to something different than {100,50} it doesn't change the location?

Comment: that exactly what it does, no changes

Comment: See if you are not changing it from some other thread than the main thread?